# Salt Stack environments ignoring saltenv

Tags: configuration, salt

I have a salt master with four environments configured (base, dev, staging, prod)

I am initially trying to set a pillar item to track which envrionment is in use, namely core:env

However when I try to switch environments using the following command I always get the dev environment (it doesn't matter what env I put)

`salt 'deploy*' pillar.get core:env saltenv=base`

Here are my config files

```
/etc/salt/master (partial)
file_roots:
  base:
    - /srv/salt/base/states
  dev:
    - /srv/salt/dev/states
    - /srv/salt/base/states
  staging:
    - /srv/salt/staging/states
    - /srv/salt/base/states
  prod:
    - /srv/salt/prod/states
    - /srv/salt/base/states


pillar_roots:
  base:
    - /srv/pillar/base/pillars
  dev:
    - /srv/pillar/dev/pillars
    - /srv/pillar/base/pillars
  staging:
    - /srv/pillar/staging/pillars
    - /srv/pillar/base/pillars
  prod:
    - /srv/pillar/prod/pillars
    - /srv/pillar/base/pillars
```

and my pillars

```
root@Salt-Master:/srv/pillar# cat base/pillars/top.sls
base:
  'deploy':
    - core
root@Salt-Master:/srv/pillar# cat base/pillars/core.sls
core:
  env: base
root@Salt-Master:/srv/pillar# cat dev/pillars/top.sls
dev:
  'deploy':
    - core
root@Salt-Master:/srv/pillar# cat dev/pillars/core.sls
core:
  env: dev
```

(the rest follow the same pattern)

I have other data in the base pillar that is being pulled out, but the core:env item won't change from dev.

Answer (score 2):

State and pillar environments are set independently.

Specifing

```
environment: prod
```

in the minion configuration will force the minion to use the prod state, but it will still use the default pillar data. To select a pillar environment you will also need:

```
pillarenv: prod
```

This also does not work in old versions of salt and [is only supported with pillar.get as of salt version 2016.3,](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/36629) so you may be in need of an update.